# How to build a good Java GUI application design pattern?

Tags: java, user-interface, design-patterns, panel, wrapper

I'm wondering about Java GUI panels programming in a good way. My main concern is about methods, panels, labels, listeners, initializing - where?

Where i'm suppose to place these things, how i have to place them between panel and wrapper ( controller too maybe).

Let's say that I have to programm MenuPanel with MenuPanelWrapper containing some buttons and so on. How to do this in a best way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way to create some Java UI is to use the **MVC** [(model-view-controleur)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.

Let's suppose that: we have a **JButton**, **JLabel** and a **JTextField** in our Java UI, like this :

[image: MVC step 1]

On the left we have the **UI** and on the right we have the design of the **MVC**. In this UI, the user can put some text in the JTextField, and display it in the JLabel by pressing the JButton.

- The **View** contains the JLabel, because the View represents the data of the Model. (And in some case the View can also refresh the UI by hidding or adding some actions : like hidding/adding some JButton or removing some listener).
- The **Model** contains the data to display, and retrieve the data send by the Controler. The Model is not directly visible in the UI. It's like a black box that we can just manipulate it by the Controler and see his data by the View.
- The **Controler** contains the JButton and the JTextField. The Controler will change the value of the Model, and the Model will alert the View to refresh himself (in this case the JLabel).

***Step 1***

Now if the user change the value of the JTextField, this will affect the JtextField of the **Controler**.

[image: MVC step 2]

***Step 2***

If the user press the JButton, the **Controler** will change the value of the **Model.valueLabel** by calling the setter of the **Model**.

[image: MVC step 3]

***Step 3***

At this step, the **Model** will notify his **View** that the value of the **Model.valueLabel** has changed. And the **View** will refresh himself (by changing the value of the JLabel). Finally, the JLabel display the value of the data **Model**.

[image: MVC step 4]

***Step 4*** *- In some case*

After the **View** has finished his refresh, he can refresh the **Controler** by adding or disabling some actions.

[image: MVC step 5]

---

**EDIT**

P.S: Sometimes the view and the controler are *together* and it's more like a Model and ViewControler, when we cannot separate the View and the Controler.

Comment: Thanks You for Your answer! It was really helpfull!